# Why does GeoServer WMS not work in OpenLayers? problem viewing Geoserver layers

Tags: c#, gis, geoserver

Adding two layer using open layer one map layer from OSM second layer adding from geoserver localhost. But when I load single  OSM layer its showing by default map.

Its ok but

when adding second layer its not working. its also disappear old layer map also

```
var MapLayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
        });
        var myView = new ol.View({
            center: [74.1296577, 32.2739606],
            zoom: 4,
            projection: projection
        });
        var mymap = new ol.source.TileWMS({
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/DHAGIS/wms',
            params: { 'LAYERS': 'DHAGIS:baddoki', 'TILED': true, 'STYLES': 'graves' },
            serverType: 'geoserver',

        });
        var mylayer = new ol.layer.Tile({
            source=mymap
        });
        //////////////////////////
        var map = new ol.Map({
            target: 'map',
            layers: [MapLayer, mylayer
            ],
            view: myView
        });
```

Comment: Well, a WMS produces an image, that usualy can´t be stacked one over the other. Thus the topmost one hides those layers beyond. You would need some transparency in your layers. Aside from this your quesrtion is better suited at gis.stackexchange.com